# How to run selenium Webdriver test cases in Firefox C#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, firefoxdriver

TestFixture:

```
class TestForFirefox
{
    IWebDriver driver = null;
    [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    [Test]
    public void OpenAppTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.demoqa.com");
    }
    [TearDown]
    public void CloseApp()
    {
        driver.Quit();
        driver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Packages I have installed:

1. NUnit 2.6.4
2. NUnit Test Adapter 2.0.0
3. Selenium Firefox Webdriver 0.11.1
4. Selenium Support 2.53.1
5. Selenium Webdriver 2.53.1

My OS: Windows 10 and Firefox Ver: 48.0.2

While running this code it shows:
object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you import this Firefox driver? Did you configure it before using it?

Comment: Yes i have imported Firefox.

Comment: I have used using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium 2.53.1 is not supported in Firefox 48, you will need to downgrade to Firefox 47 or use the Geckodriver instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930370/selenium-2-53-or-2-48-not-working-in-firefox-48-0

Answer (score 0):

Change the top part of your code:

```
public static IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
[SetUp]
public void Initialize()
{
    Driver = new FirefDriverDriver()
}
```